# Telethon: iter_messages with offset_date does't work

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have a question in Telethon library and Client method as `iter_messages` ([doc](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html?highlight=iter_message#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.iter_messages))

I'm trying to get all the messages from a conversation that have been in it for two hours [T; (T-2h)].

For this, i use this code:

```py
one_hour_ago: datetime = current_datetime - timedelta(hours=1)
messages_iter = client_obj.iter_messages(chat_id,
                                         limit=100,
                                         offset_date=one_hour_ago)
```

And my expectation, that i will receive all messages during t-2h and in total, count less or eq. than 100.
But instead, i got 100 messages without limit by date. Even more, when i tryed to remain only  `offset_date` parameter, iterator ignored this and conveyed all messages!

Comment: I don't know how telegram and/or telethon handle timezones, which may be the source of the problem: **Your** time at "today, 08:00" may be "today, 12:00" or "today, 04:00" on the **server**, which may mean that your "since one hour ago" is interpreted as "since 8 hours ago" or "since 2 hours in the future".
At least make sure that `current_datetime` is a timezone-aware (not "naive") object.